# Copy Activity with stored procedure rounds up decimals

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using an Azure Data Factory to get data from an on prem database to an Azure sql database.

I am doing it in 2 steps:

1. Copy to blob
2. Insert into azure using a copy activity that runs a stored procedure.

The problem i have is the decimal is rounded up and the destination values are different than source.

For the entire process i have defined 3 datasets:

1. SQLDataset - the structure node is {... "name" : "MyColumn", "type":"Decimal"}.
2. BlobDataset - the structure node is the same as above
3. AzureSQLDataset - the structure node is the same

On the SQL database, i have a user defined table type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.myType TABLE (...MyColumn decimal(28,10) null)
```

The stored procedure does an insert or an update and no data transformation. However, when i query for MyColumn value, the values end up being rounded up.

If source had a value of *266222451894.019990000* , target has a value of *266222451894.0200000000*

Am i missing something ?

Comment: I have investigated this with Microsoft support and we have identified it as a bug. There are issues when converting decimals with high precision and loads of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a precise numeric value, your best bet is to ship the numeric value out as a string.